# Limit a measure to be executed until a specific date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to create a measure that do a count and i need that to work until 03/31/currentyear.

I have a table with a comum calendar, and I tried to do the following parameter:

```
'dCalendario'[Date] <= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 03, 31)
```

I'm noob in Dax and I think that would never work, but i have to try.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using [filter](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filter-arguments-in-calculate/) example as follows

```
row_count = 

VAR datelimit = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 03, 31)

CALCULATE (
    <expression> or <Measure>,
    'dCalendario'[Date] <= datelimit 
)
```